# How to get field values by specific field type from all Entries?

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, field, entries-field, custom-fieldtype

I am trying to get all values of a specific field type from all entries. (ex.: craft\fields\PlainText)

Is there an easy way to get these values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

This function checks recursively whether a field exists with the searched type, if it is a matrix field then it searches further in it.

```php
private function filterFieldsByType($blocks, $fieldType): array
{
    $values = [];

    foreach ($blocks as $block) {
        foreach ($block->getFieldLayout()->getFields() as $field) {
            if ($field instanceof $fieldType) {
                $values[] = $block->{$field->handle};
            }
            elseif ($field instanceof \craft\fields\Matrix) {
                $values[] = $this->filterFieldsByType($block->{$field->handle}, $fieldType);
            }
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
```

This is the main function that returns all fields in which the searched field type exists, the whole is returned as an array where the fields with the values are located.

```php
public function getFieldsFromEntriesByFieldType($fieldType): array
{
    $entries = Entry::find()->all(); //Maybe batch query for better perfomance if there is a large of amount.
    $values = $this->filterFieldsByType($entries, $fieldType);

    $result = array_merge([], ...$values);
    $result = array_filter($result);
    return array_values($result);
}
```

How to use it:

```php
$fieldType = 'xxx\\myplugin\\fields\\MyCustomField';

$myCustomFieldsFromAllEntries = $this->getFieldsFromEntriesByFieldType($fieldType);
```